# What is the recommended approach to secure .NET 4.0 Web API that uses unconventional authentication method?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity, jwt

I have been researching on securing Web API and all the articles and books are pointing to use OAuth. But oauth is not suitable for my scenario as I don't need another system to authenticate the user.

An additional complexity to that is we are using out of wallet questions instead of username/password to authenticate users.

My application is an Angular UI front end with .NET 4.0 Web API backend.
I am thinking of implementing token and claim based authentication in JWT to pass as barer token but I couldn't find the good resources/samples for .NET 4.0 Web API 1. I've seen many good articles on .NET 4.5 and OWIN middlewares but none of these are usable in .NET 4.0.

I am still new to WEB API world so here are my questions.

1. Is it the recommended approach to secure Web API 1, if not, what would you recommend?
2. Can you give me some good articles/samples for Web API 1 security?
3. I am thinking of using Thinktecture.IdentityModel.40 and again, I can't find good sample for .NET 4.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a request filter to grab a token from the HTTP header. Probably the simplest way to go.

Web api has authentication filters.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters

Comment: Thanks, my main bottleneck is the correct way to implement the security token. Since I am new to Web API security, I am not even sure my approach is the right way to do it. Also your link is for Web API 2, I can't use those in Web API 1.